# boss's son told a lie about me

Tags: professionalism, unprofessional-behavior

There are 2 bosses/owners at my company.  I work for one boss and another woman works for the other boss.  The other boss's son also works for the company.  The other woman was unhappy with her raise and made a stink about it.  The boss's son told his dad that she was upset because I showed her my paycheck and after finding out how much more I was making became irate. (The other boss told my boss that I did this, as well.) I absolutely would never show her my paycheck.  I have 20 years on this woman and have worked in HR that entire time and know that is a huge no-no.  The son said that he saw me do it.

I confronted the son and asked him why he said that to his dad when it didn't happen.  He denied having said it.  He said that the other woman knew how much I made and was upset but he didn't tell me how she knew.  I asked him to go to his dad and clear up the "misunderstanding" as this was my reputation on the line.  I have been there 9 years and it is important for me to have the other boss know that he can trust me.  He said he would tell him that night.  The next day, the son didn't come to work.  The other boss has said nothing to me about it so my guess is he didn't tell him.  What do I do now?

My boss believes me so that is not an issue.  I recorded the conversation that the son and I had on my phone.  I would be very reluctant to ever pull that out and use it.  I also think that the other woman found out how much I make by looking at my w2 when it was delivered by courier in an unsealed envelope but I can't prove that.  Do I let this go if he refuses to fess up or do I put my foot down.  He has lied about so many other things and I know that his dad knows he is lying about them and they must be awful for him. But this is a lie about me. I'm not ok with that.

Comment: I *really* hope you are in a jurisdiction that allows single party consent on recording conversations.  Varies state to state in US and I won't even pretend to know about other countries.  You might want to find out about that before you think about bringing out that recording.

Comment: You said the boss already is on your side and knows that you are telling the truth, so what do you hope to accomplish by having the son confess?  Is it just for retribution?  In a business environment it may be better to let it go as long as management is not holding it against you.

Comment: I did confirm that Colorado is a single party consent state before that conversation.  I think that my concern is that the other boss in the company, the father of the liar, believes what his son has said.  I don't work for him directly, but I still care what his impression of me is.

Answer (score 3):

You know he's lying, they know he's lying, he knows he's lying. He's a liar, plenty of them around, probably the only reason he's employed there is his relationship.

You're safe, don't let it frustrate you and don't push it. My sons don't lie, but when push comes to shove I'll back them 100%, at that point I don't care whether they're in the right or not, it's my boys.

Answer (score 2):

You say that:

> this is a lie about me. I'm not ok with that.

That's understandable. But you also say...

> My boss believes me so that is not an issue.
>
> I know that his dad knows he is lying about them and they must be awful for him.

**It sounds like there's nothing more you need to do**. Both your bosses know that the son is trying to stir up trouble, and are unlikely to believe him if he keeps trying. Your other colleague presumably knows what actually happened. You've been a trusted employee for nine years and you have no reason to think that will change. If the issue comes up, calmly make it clear that you have nothing to do with it, but otherwise, it sounds like trying to force the issue has no real benefit and risks you seeming like you're looking to pursue a grudge.